# Are unused Start Worlds shuffled into the card supply?

Tags: race-for-the-galaxy

When you begin play and randomly hand out the start worlds, do you shuffle the remaining start worlds into the deck?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes: per the Setup section of the rulebook:

> Find and shuffle the five start worlds. Deal one world face up to each
>   player. These form  each player’s initial card tableau.
>
> **Shuffle the unused start worlds together with the game cards.** Deal six face down cards to each  player. Each player then examines these
>   cards and discards two cards face down to the discard  pile. The
>   remaining game cards form the initial card supply.

[Bolded by me for emphasis.]

Comment: Note that as you add expansions, fishing the start worlds back out of the deck after you play becomes a bigger pain in the rear, so sometimes my group just skips this part and leaves the extras out for expedience.

Comment: My group eventually put card sleeves on the cards, and used different-colored card sleeves for the starting cards.  We *really* didn't like hunting through the deck for the starting cards.